# Can't build basic rest-api project in Grails 3.1.0

Tags: grails, gradle

I've just created a test project in Grails 3.1.0 that uses the new rest-api profile:

```
grails create-app rest-test --profile=rest-api
```

Without any modifications, when I try and `gradle build` the application the build fails:

```
cd rest-test
gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
:processResources
:classes
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:compileIntegrationTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileIntegrationTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:buildProperties
:compileGsonViews
Invalid arguments: [C:\projects\rest-test\grails-app\views,C:\projects\rest-test\build\gson-classes\main,1.8,rest-test,C:\projects\rest-test\grails-app\conf\application.yml,UTF-8]

Usage: java -cp CLASSPATH grails.plugin.json.view.JsonViewCompiler [srcDir] [destDir] [targetCompatibility] [packageImports] [packageName] [configFile] [encoding]

:compileGsonViews FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGsonViews'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Looking at that error message, it seems there aren't enough arguments passed to the java call.

If I do a `grails run-app` I'm able to start the app successfully and can see the gson views at localhost:8080.

Does anyone have any ideas why the `gradle build` command is failing?

Comment: Which version of Gradle? It is advisable to use `gradle wrapper` for better compatibility. Try using `gradlew clean build`

Comment: @dmahapatro - I just checked and same issue. Using either gradle 2.9 or 2.10.

Comment: I ran into the same problem when I wanted to create a rest-api application without domain classes, only with few controllers. "run-app" was working fine, but any attempt to create a WAR ended up with the same error you've got. The error went away after a created a dummy domain class without any content. Interestingly, this problem only happens if you use "rest-api" profile, but the same steps work file if you create a grails app with default "web" profile. Apparently, there's a bug in "rest-api" profile, which doesn't allow to build the application if there's no domain classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution on **[Grails GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9631)**:

> Please replace the line
>
> ```
>     classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.0.1"
> ```
>
> With
>
> ```
>     classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.0.3"
> ```
>
> In your `build.gradle` file

I tested it with Grails 3.1.2 -- **it works!**